# Completely New to SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've been given a project at my job involving SharePoint. I'm eventually supposed to replace our current Intranet site and and website using SharePoint.

I've never used SharePoint before and was wondering where a good place to start would be. I also have little knowledge of website design in the first place. Can anyone reccomend a book or a detailed site that will explain things to me like I'm an idiot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's always hard suggesting beginner's books because you never know where to start.

Sharepoint, as with all software, is best learned by playing with it. You said you are supposed to replace your current intranet site with Sharepoint. The best thing you can do right now is set up a little test environment with Sharepoint. I say "a little" because in the end it is not that hard, but looking at the documentation from Microsoft: [Setting Up the Development Environment for SharePoint 2010 on Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28office.14%29.aspx), it is hard ;-)

Microsoft also offers the [2010 Information Worker Demonstration and Evaluation Virtual Machine (RTM)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=751fa0d1-356c-4002-9c60-d539896c66ce&displaylang=en) - a whopping 3GB download (you only need `2010-7a`). Mind you: this Virtual machine only runs under Windows Server 2008 R2 with Hyper-V activated, so not on your standard issue Windows XP.
Talking of which: Sharepoint 2010 needs a 64 Bit System (go with Windows Server 2008 to make yourself happy) and at least 8GB of RAM.

That being said of some test system you can play with (create some document libraries, look at workflows, get yourself accustomed to master pages etc.) there are of course some theoretical books. You asked about *explain things to me like I'm an idiot?*, lucky you: [Amazon's choice of Sharepoint 2010 for Dummies](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=sharepoint+2010+dummies&x=0&y=0) books. If you know the "for Dummies" series - the books are not very in depth, but they are o.k. at giving a general picture.
If you want more professional books, there is [SharePoint 2010 User's Guide: Learning Microsoft's Business Collaboration Platform](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143022763X) or [Beginning SharePoint 2010 Development (Wrox Beginning Guides)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470584637).

Btw: The best tool to start your customization efforts, once you have your test environment is Microsoft's Sharepoint Designer 2010. It's a breeze creating custom master pages or changing some CSS quickly.

The first tasks I would set for myself after understanding a bit of Sharepoint: Customize a standard Sharepoint Site (Team Site, Publishing, ...) to match my companies appearance. Some hints: Look at Themes, Master Pages, Layouts.

Comment: We've got a virtual machine set up with Windows Server 2008 and SharePoint installed on that. Would the best way to create a Publishing Site be to go through the Central Administration Console and create a new site collection with the Publishing Template? Or do it from the default Team Site that I have now? Site Actions -> New Site.

Comment: You just need to activate the publishing and publishing infrastructure features on your existing site - the template doesn't do much beyond what's in those features.

Comment: What Tom said. Team Site is a good site to start (Also the Wiki Template has nice features too easily see what Sharepoint is "capable" of). To activate Publishing features go to Site Actions > Site Settings > Site Collection Features > Sharepoint Server Publishing Infrastructure and Activate it. Same goes for Site Features > Sharepoint Server Publishing.