# Sharepoint Development tutorials

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

Can any one please help me find some good tutorials for sharepoint 2010 as i am pretty new to this i have worked on visual stodio 2010 and sql server.But i don't have any clue about Sharepoint for development
neither i know what to search
Can any onyone please help me with that it will be really very helpful

Thanks

I have tried various links on youtube but nothing is giving me inner sights of sharepoint

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7c-6GrWuwbQ

Comment: You should have a look at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try any of the below methods to get started:

### Books

- [Wrox - Beginning Sharepoint 2010 Development](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-0470584637.html)
- [Microsoft Press - Inside Microsoft SharePoint 2010](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780735627468.do)
- *([Some more help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981467/completely-new-to-sharepoint-2010))*

### Video Tutorials

- [pluralsight.com](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses#sharepoint)

  - [SharePoint 2010 Developer Ramp-Up](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/cpt-sp2010-admin-ramp-part1) (Series)
  - [SharePoint 2010 Fundamentals](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/sp2010-foundation-fundamentals)
  - [SharePoint 2010 Development](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/sp2010-development)